# Can I estimate the real or final price of a plane trip?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, bookings, low-cost-carriers

I am not so sure that LCC are really "low cost". The hidden [fees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAg0lUYHHFc), usually tend to increase the total price to a similar or even higher value than one for a flight on a regular airline.

I had some really bad experiences with this famous yellow and blue carrier, that I am now only considering a LCC when there is no other option.

I am looking for a honest comparison between all flights (LCC and normal operating airlines) on a given route.

Is there anyway to estimate the true expected price to be paid (the ticket, fees that are part of the ticket, and fees that are charged at the airport) when flying from A to B on a LCC, other than going through pages of small letters on the carrier's website?

Comment: I use www.momondo.com, they're not perfect but more realistic (apparently they just don't include credit card for Easyjet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see your video so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "hidden fees", but maybe [KAYAK's comparison table of airline fees for baggage, meals, pets, minors, and extra legroom](http://www.kayak.com/airline-fees) would be a helpful starting point.

Regarding baggage fees specifically, [KAYAK's flight search](http://www.kayak.com/flights) lets you include these when comparing flight prices. After performing a search, click "Show Toolbox" at the top of the left navigation bar, then "Add Baggage" and input the number of checked bags.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what parts of the world or what airlines you might be interested in, but British Airways have [a calculator](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/value-calculator/public/en_gb?source=R04TPC134999410180600D) for comparing their fares against Ryanair and EasyJet, including "hidden" fees. Of course, you have to take it with a pinch of salt as obviously they are trying to sell their product, but it's still useful if you're looking at the UK market.